# Jest: Cannot find module 'monaco-editor-core'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, monaco-editor, ts-jest

I have an reactjs(typescript) app which uses monaco-editor-core, and not monaco-editor, with custom language. Jest tests fails, if i don't mock monaco-editor-core imports, with next error:

```
"Cannot find module 'monaco-editor-core'",
```

From posts which I read I understood that jest doesn't support ESM. That's why there is monaco-editor-webpack-plugin was written, which doesn't work with monaco-editor-core.
Maybe someone knows how can I fix import issue for monaco-editor-core for jest?

- jest: 26.4.2
- ts-jest: 26.3.0
- typescript: 3.9.5
- react: 16.9.0
- monaco-editor-core: 0.21.3
- webpack: 4.42.1

If I use moduleNameMapper at jest.config.js:

```
"monaco-editor-core": "<rootDir>/node_modules/monaco-editor-core/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts"
```

I have next error:

```
 .../node_modules/monaco-editor-core/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.d.ts:6
    declare global {
            ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at compileFunction (<anonymous>)
```

Comment if you need any additional info which can help.

PS: I can't tag it as monaco-editor-core...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding of this to my `jest.config.json` worked for me:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules\/(?!(monaco-editor|monaco-editor-core)\/)"
]
```